# Creating schema using pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, schema

I need some guidance/help with a simple task to create a schema in Apache Pig for my data file. I have two files that would contribute to this task. First file is a data file which contains the data with no column header, and a second file contains the column header for the data file. So basically, the column_header file is the schema for the data file. How do i outline this in a pig script? Here's what i got so far.

```
column_header = load 'sitecatalyst/coulmn_headers.tsv' using PigStorage('\t');
data = load 'sitecatalyst/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t') as column_header;
schema = foreach data generate column_header;
store schema into 'output1' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
withSchema = load 'output1';
describe withSchema;
```

This is the output for

```
DUMP column_header
```

(accept_language,browser,browser_height,browser_width)

When i do,

```
DUMP data;
```

only the first line column of data is being output, which is wrong.

en-US

en-US

en-US

en-US

Instead it should be,

en-US   638 755 1600

en-US   638 655 1342

en-US   638 723 1612

en-US   638 231 1234

How can i trick Pig to use "column_header" as a string that can be use during the PigStorage AS statement on the second line of code?

Edit:
This code will work but instead of hard-coding my column_header i would like pig script to read it instead.

```
column_header = load 'sitecatalyst/coulmn_headers.tsv' using PigStorage('\t');
data = load 'sitecatalyst/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t') as (accept_language,browser,browser_height,browser_width);
schema = foreach data generate accept_language,browser,browser_height,browser_width;
store schema into 'output1' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
withSchema = load 'output1';
describe withSchema;
```

Comment: question is not clear  what u need ..

Comment: Hi Sandeep, which part of the question is not clear? I just need to create a schema for my data file. And i have a file which contains the column headers for the data file. How do i achieve this?

Comment: what are you looking you want to set header for out put file or any thing else u are doing...

Comment: I do not want to set header or whatsoever. I just need the documentation design (Schema) for the data file. Which in the code i am output it to a file.

Comment: feel it is not the correct way of creating design document.

Answer (score 0):

you can not achieve such parameterization from in the pig script directly,
you can to the same thing by

```
data = load 'sitecatalyst/hit_data.tsv' using PigStorage('\t') as $column_header;
schema = foreach data generate column_header;
store schema into 'output1' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
withSchema = load 'output1';
describe withSchema;
```

and run the pig script by ,
pig -param_file (location of the file) column

The file should be of the format
column_header = complete schema

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2014/08/12/how-to-use-parameter-substitution-with-pig-latin-and-powershell/

Comment: Do you tried that ? I think `$column_header` will be substituted by a literal string which not suitable for specifying schema !

Comment: Hi @pratiklodha, Thanks for taking your time. I tried the solution you provide but it is not working. Because the file column_header is being delimited by tabs. And when i do `AS $column_header` it should have in this format:  (accept_language,browser,browser_height,browser_width) which i can get from `DUMP column_header`. Sorry for my bad explanation